# % operator in python over string

Tags: python, string-formatting

What does the following Python statement mean?

```
send_data=""
str_len = "%#04d" % (len(send_data)/2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sets `str_len` to show half the length of `send_data`, padded with zeros to be four characters right. The `%` character is carrying out **interpolation**. See the [*printf-style String Formatting*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) section of the documentation.